# Unable to launch any app installed using `dpkg -i`

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 22.04, dpkg

I am unable to launch any app installed using `dpkg -i`. I'm using Firefox to download the `.deb` file. When I install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i app_name.deb
```

I can't run it normally. I need to use:

```
app_name --no-sandbox
```

to run the app. I can't open it using GUI or by  running `app_name` in terminal, as normal.

How to fix this?

Here are some details about my system:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

$ uname -a
Linux pegasus 5.19.0-1007-nvidia-lowlatency #7-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jan 25 00:08:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score -1):

The `--no-sandbox` parameter is app/program specific. We need to know what app you are trying to run to understand what `--no-sandbox` means to that command and why you need it.

If it's chrome/chromium, or some other app based on them, then it's because you are running it as root or through `sudo`, and it doesn't support running at all as root without `--no-sandbox`

Comment: Whatever app .deb image I'm downloading it's showing same result.
For example I had currently faced this thing with
microsoft-edge-stable and vscode